# How do you make a patch showing the difference between the branch before the first commit and the last committed version in the same branch?

Tags: git

I have a branch called ticket20 and I made 10 commits, I want to make a patch that shows the diff between ticket20 when I first created it (0 commit) and now (10th commit). I know you can make a patch with git diff, but I don't know how to target the 0th commit and the 10th commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you branched off `master`,

```
git diff master...ticket20
```

If you branched off a remote or otherwise tracked your branchpoint with `git branch -t` or `git config branch.autosetupmerge true`,

```
git diff ticket20@{u}...ticket20
```

If you've got it checked out,

```
git diff @{u}...
```

The three-dot syntax is specific to diff, it means "since the merge base".

Answer (score 1):

You should find out what commit your branch diverges from (the commit that `master` and `ticket20` have in common).
If you are on Linux, you can use `gitk` as a graphical tool or `git log --pretty=oneline --all --graph` for a CLI approach.

Once you have found that commit, you can create a diff from this commit to your current `HEAD`:

```
git diff [yourhash] HEAD
```

Or if you just want to get a diff of the latest 10 commits:

```
git diff HEAD~10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `~` sign to use the last 10 commits.
This sign

Using the git diff command:

```
git diff HEAD~10...HEAD
```

Using the log command

```
git log HEAD...HEAD~10
```

The purpose of the `..` is to mark a range of commits.