# Git - how to find first commit and get changed files of specific branche

Tags: git

In following example tree:

```
A-B-C-D-E (master branch)
    \
     F-G-H (xxx branch)
```

I'm looking for B. I need to get all changed files from xxx branch:

```
git diff B H
```

To get B, I tried:

```
git cherry master xxx | tail -1
```

but I'm getting commit F and if I make diff between F and H I don't have changed files from F.

Thanks for help.

David

Comment: `if I make diff between F and H I don't have changed files from F` ... what does this mean?

Comment: I *think*, as jbu answered, that you're looking for `git merge-base`. Note that `git diff` has a built-in syntax to diff the merge base of two specific commits against one of those two specific commits, too: `git diff master...xxx` (note THREE, not two, dots).

Comment: you probably mean C not B, don't you? C is not any kind of "fork commit", just regular commit happened before branching, and branch contains it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a patch showing the difference between the branch before the first commit and the last committed version in the same branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530741/how-do-you-make-a-patch-showing-the-difference-between-the-branch-before-the-fir)

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what you're asking - are you asking how to find B? if so try

```
git merge-base master xxx
```

This will get you the most recent common ancestor between master and xxx